# O que é o status http/ftp 220?

Tags: http, ftp, http-status

Contextualizando... ao tentar conectar no servidor de hospedagem, por FTP, retorna sempre o status 220 e, depois de alguns segundos, desconecta pelo tempo

Por ser um status do tipo 2xx não é um erro nem meu (4xx) nem no servidor (5xx), mas algum problema tem (já que não conecta), então o que significa esse status?

Apesar de dar um contexto à pergunta, uma resposta geral é bem vinda

Comment: Pesquisando bem por cima, encontrei o seguinte: *220 - Service ready for new user.* No serviço de hospedagem em questão não tem algo em específico pra esse caso?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim valeu, se tem não encontrei

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo na wikipedia tem o 220? Não encontrei, nem nos não oficiais

Comment: @Isac, se é o que quer saber, o site está hospedado na locaweb

Comment: O que comentei encontrei na [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes), mas no que se referia a erros de ftp, fiquei curioso sobre o seu caso :p

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim valeu pelo link, se souber de mais alguma coisa pode tentar uma resposta mais completa

Comment: Qual o FTP cliente que vc tá usando?

Comment: @sam uso o filezila

Comment: Um comentário bem importante: FTP é diferente de HTTP. São protocolos diferentes e possuem [códigos de retorno diferentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes).

Comment: Vc quer saber FTP ou HTTP? No título e nas tags falam HTTP e no texto FTP, que são coisas diferentes

Comment: Caro Guilherme, independente de qual resposta vc aceitou fazer este tipo de edição depois de respondido descaracteriza respostas já dadas, por favor evite este tipo de situação

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A pergunta foi editada corretamente na [revisão número 3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/316969/3) e depois
>   revertida para o original sem nenhuma razão aparente. Vou me basear no
>   protocolo FTP, já que como já foi dito, o status 220 não existe no HTTP.

A resposta 220 significa que a conexão foi estabelecida (SYN) e o servidor está pronto para receber as credenciais (caso necessite). Esse status se dá após os 3 *handshakes* iniciais pela porta TCP 21 conforme diagrama abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, o cliente envia uma solicitação SYN (de sincronizar) para o servidor (1º passo), este responde com SYN-ACK (sincronizar-tomou conhecimento, 2º passo) e o cliente devolve um ACK (tomou conhecimento, 3º passo).

Após o 3º passo o servidor envia o status 220 informando que a conexão foi estabelecida e novamente o cliente envia o ACK (tomou conhecimento) juntamente com as credenciais (usuário e senha ou apenas usuário se o servidor permitir conexão anônima).

Em relação a estar desconectando sozinho após alguns segundos "pelo tempo", pode ser N fatores, desde tempo de inatividade ou devido a alguma configuração no cliente.

Seguem alguns links de referência sobre conexões FTP:

- http://blog.eventhelix.com/2013/05/10/ftp-file-transfer-protocolsequence-diagram/
- https://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml

Comment: Como comentei na outra resposta, não sabia que exista status ftp, achava que esses valores eram universais. Editei a pergunta corigindo tags e título. Em relação ao "pelo tempo", acredito ser alguma configuração no próprio filezilla para não manter a conexão aberta por muito tempo, valeu pela resposta

Comment: Tem opção lá que você seta o tempo de inatividade antes de desconectar.

Comment: Convido você a se manifestar aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7203/132

Answer (score 7):

**FTP não é HTTP,** são protocolos diferentes, funcionam com ferramentas diferentes, tem diferentes propósitos.

**Não existe** código HTTP 220, o que existem no range de 200 são:

- 200 OK
- 201 Created
- 202 Accepted
- 203 Non-Authoritative Information (since HTTP/1.1)
- 204 No Content
- 205 Reset Content
- 206 Partial Content (RFC 7233)
- 207 Multi-Status (WebDAV; RFC 4918)
- 208 Already Reported (WebDAV; RFC 5842)
- 226 IM Used (RFC 3229)

O código especificamente 220 é FTP, segue a descrição:

> Service ready for new user.
>
> Traduzindo: Serviço pronto para novo usuário

Isto indica que o servidor esta pronto para que um usuário se conecte e por isto recebe tal código, conforme o link http://www.serv-u.com/kb/1509/220-FTP-Reply-Code

Ao usar o comando `REIN` (comando que reinicia) que finaliza o usuário atual, o protocolo pode enviar o código 220, este comando

> REINITIALIZE (REIN)
>
> This command terminates a USER, flushing all I/O and account
> information, except to allow any transfer in progress to be completed.
> All parameters are reset to the default settings and the control
> connection is left open.  This is identical to the state in which a
> user finds himself immediately after the control connection is opened.
> A USER command may be expected to follow.
>
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959

Comment: Não sabia que exista status ftp, achava que esses valores eram universais, valeu

Comment: Editei a pergunta, o que acha?